# Need help Dynamically resizing my text to fit in the tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I was working on a small python script lately when I came across this problem. I tried to create a canvas in a strip shape and write text into it expecting that the text would auto adjust itself to the boundaries of canvas(similar to how a text box works in word processing software). But the text is apparently going out of boundaries.

**ScreenShot** [image: Display of text going out of canvas boundary]

**Code**

```
from tkinter import *
top = Tk()  
top.geometry("130x370")
c = Canvas(top,bg = "pink",height = "370")
c.create_text(30,30,fill="darkblue",font="Times 20 italic bold",text="Hey There!")
c.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you really need to use a `Canvas`? The `Text` widget wrap the text automatically.

Comment: For clarification: You do not actually want to _resize_ the text (change the font size) but _wrap_ the text, right? What, if any, is the reason you do not use a text field? And how should it behave if the canvas is completely "full" (vertically)?

Comment: Well, I was not sure if a text field would do the job right and if the canvas is full vertically, the entire text should be resized to fit in the canvas. Just think of it as an application where text is taken as an input and printed onto an image of custom size.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the `.create_text()` method of the `Canvas` has a `width` option which sets the maximum width of the text beyond which it is wrapped. To get a dynamical effect when resizing the window, this `width` option can be changed in a function bound to the `<Configure>` event (the `resize()` function in the example below).

Secondly, to check that the text fits vertically in the canvas, I use the `.bbox(item_id)` method of the `Canvas` to get the coordinates of the bounding box of the text. Then, I decrement the fontsize as long as the bottom of the text is lower than the bottom of the canvas.

Here is the example:

```
import tkinter as tk
top = tk.Tk()
top.geometry("130x370")

def resize(event):
    font = "Times %i italic bold"
    fontsize = 20
    x0 = c.bbox(text_id)[0] # x-coordinate of the left side of the text
    c.itemconfigure(text_id, width=c.winfo_width() - x0, font=font % fontsize)
    # shrink to fit
    height = c.winfo_height() # canvas height
    y1 = c.bbox(text_id)[3] # y-coordinate of the bottom of the text
    while y1 > height and fontsize > 1:
        fontsize -= 1
        c.itemconfigure(text_id, font=font % fontsize)
        y1 = c.bbox(text_id)[3]

c = tk.Canvas(top, bg="pink", height="370")
text_id = c.create_text(30, 30, anchor="nw", fill="darkblue", font="Times 20 italic bold", text="Hey There!")
c.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
c.bind("<Configure>", resize)

top.mainloop()
```

Also note that I set the anchor of the text to north west in `.create_text()` so that (30, 30) are the coordinates of the top-left corner of the text and not of the center to ensure that the start of the text is visible.